# Amazon Web Service Bill

Tags: amazon-web-services

I wanted to practice with AWS, so I created my account with my bank account which has no money in it in case I made some stupid mistake in charging. I used the service for 1 month and AWS just sent me an email with the charge $1200. Do I need to pay the bill? I don't mind if they erase all my data because they are just dummy data.

Comment: This is probably not the place for questions like this.  My initial reaction is yes, you have to pay the bill although there may be a dispute process you can go through to reclaim any costs you feel might have be incurred erroneously.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. I am so confused about AWS Service, so I posted questions. BTW, I have just searched Google "Why are Stack Overflow guys so mean"

Comment: Ok, you've probably learned a valuable lesson regarding cloud services but I hope it didn't come at too greater cost!  If I came across mean, I apologise, I never intended to. I guess we're all just trying to ensure the questions and answers on this site are applicable to programming so it serves as a concise and useful resource for future users. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can raise a ticket with AWS billing and ask them why and where this much charges incur. 
If you have signed up new, then 12 months of basic service is free in which you should be covered. 
Looks like an issue from  them, but AWS billing team is helpful. All the best !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got panic the whole day. It is odd because I just tried S3 Service, but somehow I got charged with Elastic Compute Cloud Service.

Comment: Please note that the [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) is merely a pricing discount for a certain amount of some services. Usage outside of these amounts will incur normal charges. I agree that you should contact AWS Customer Service (not Customer Support) and they look at your account and  explain things better.